# Google Analytics API - Confused by what "ids" represents

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the GA API in my web app, and one of the analytics looks like this:

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function () {

   /*
    * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
    * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
    * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
    */
        gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
            container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
            clientid: 'xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        });

   /**
    * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
    * element with the id "view-selector-container".
    */
        var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
            container: 'view-selector-container'
        });

        // Render the view selector to the page.
        viewSelector.execute();

   /*
    * Create a new DataChart instance with the given query parameters
    * and Google chart options. It will be rendered inside an element
    * with the id "chart-container".
    */
        var dataChart1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
                metrics: 'ga:newUsers, ga:users',
                dimensions: 'ga:date',
                'start-date': beginDate,
                'end-date': endDate
            },
            chart: {
                container: 'chart1-container',
                type: 'COLUMN',
                options: {
                    width: '100%',
                    isStacked: true
                }
            }
        });

         /*
         * Render the dataChart on the page whenever a new view is selected.
         */
        viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
            dataChart1.set({ query: { ids: ids } }).execute();
        });
});
```

The issue is this. When I execute this analytics from my laptop, it executes exactly as I would expect. However, if I attempt to execute it from another device, no chart is rendered from GA and no error is generated. I'm guessing, but really have no idea, the problem is with the viewSelector.on statement at the bottom where it's expecting "ids" values. However, I don't know what these values are, or what GA is expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are using this script on browser, where you logged in to GA(laptop) - and it working fine.
But from another device it might not work, because you were not authorized in Google Analytics for ID, which data you are trying to visualize.

Ideally, if you are not authorized you should see auth button, as mentioned on code comments:

> If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
>       * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're logged in with the same Google Account or with account that has access to the Google Analytics View you want reports from.

'ids' stands for the ID of Google Analytics View. It should be in format 'ga:123456789'.

See [Reference Guide [Query Parameters Summary](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#q_summary).

Answer (score 1):

The default landing page for the Google Analytics website, once logged in, is the Reporting Page.  Navigate to Admin (top menu), then click View Settings.  Your View ID will be displayed there.

[image]

[image]

[image]